# Android Push Notification - App Badge Icon for all devices

Tags: android, firebase-notifications

In my Application, I am using firebase Push Notification. I want to show App icon badge (Dot on the App icon) for all version devices like Whatsapp, & facebook , while new push notification.

From Android 8 , Badges are showing only by turn on the Settings( In Mobile -> Application Settings -> Notification -> App icon badge  -> On )

By Default I need that this settings to be turned On & I want to show badges for below Android 8 Also.
I referred many sites. Can anybody please guide me exactly to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you get any solution for that?  I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

As per official docs, Android 8 onwards, These dots appear by default in launcher apps that support them and there's nothing your app needs to do

Please refer official doc - https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

Regarding Whatsapp and FB- It seems badge functionality is enabled by default by manufacturers for these apps. Even whatsapp says Badge count is a notification functionality provided by your launcher and is not a function of WhatsApp. For ref- https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/troubleshooting/problems-with-badge-count/?lang=en